# global variable without threads

Tags: c, linux

I have this wired thing:

```
typedef enum { X, Y } cmd;
cmd _cmd;
..
..

_cmd = X; //global variable
some_var = 5;
foo(...., &_cmd);

_cmd = Y;
some_var = 6;
foo(...., &_cmd);
```

my bug happens when calling foo the second time. it appears that inside foo the value in &_cmd is X (instead of what i expect - Y).

but, if I add some printf after _cmd = Y; the bug doesn't happen - in &_cmd I have Y.
How can that be ?

I know that printf is a "slow" command,but still dont understand what's going on.

There are no threads in my program, so I didn't added any locks.
also, &_cmd value isn't changed in foo.
I'm working on linux, programing in c.

Comment: Does this compile? `cmd` is a type!

Comment: How is `foo()` declared and how do you test for `X` or `Y` inside it?

Comment: in foo() there is a switch case according to _cmd

Comment: Better show the relevant code, as this is not a guessing game.

Comment: On the face of it, there is nothing wrong with the heavily elided code you have shown us, so implicitly you have not shown enough code to determine the problem.  I say "nothing wrong", because in all cases globals should be avoided and it isn't at all clear it is justified in this example, and prefixing variables `_` is strictly *reserved*.

Comment: If it "appears that inside foo" something is wrong, it would make sense to let us see *inside* foo!

Comment: What is a "wired thing"?  What has the performance of `printf` to do with your question!?

Answer (score 0):

> it appears that inside foo the value in &_cmd is X (instead of what i expect - Y).

I would expect `&_cmd` to have the address of `_cmd` and neither X nor Y.  The bug is almost certainly in `foo()` which you have not provided.

Given the following for example:

```
void foo( cmd* arg )
{
    printf( "%d", (int)*arg ) ;  // Value pointed to by local arg.
    printf( "%d", (int)*_cmd) ;  // Value pointed to by global _cmd.
}
```

then for the call `foo( &_cmd ) ;` both outputs will be the same (and whatever was assigned to `_cmd`) because `arg == &_cmd`.